# How to execute python code by django html button?

Tags: html, django, django-views

I want to execute my python code by onclick. I am getting result after running the server. My button is not working. Here is my code.

URL -

```
url(r'^index/$', index),
```

index.html-

```
<html>
<body>
  <form action="/index/" method="GET">
    <input type="submit" value="Click">
  </form>
  {{output}}
</body>
</html>
```

views.py -

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response
from pythoncode import mycode
def index(request):
    if request.method=="GET":
        py_obj=mycode.test_code(10)
        py_obj.code()
        return render(request, 'index.html', {"output":py_obj.a})
```

I created one more application to separate python code -
application name is python code and file name mycode

```
class test_code:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a=a
        self.b=4
    def code(self):
        return self.a, self.b
```

please help me. I am new in Django. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please format your code

Comment: What exactly is the error?

Comment: I want to execute mycode.py file after click on "Click" button and show the output 10 on template. Here above exanample i am getting output 10 when i reload my page.

Comment: According to your view, the value of `{{ output }}` will be there for every GET request, not just after you submit the form. If your HTML is accurate, you are missing a closing angle bracket on the </form> tag.

Answer (score 9):

If you just want to click and display something on the fly on your page, you'll need JavaScript and AJAX. There is no need to create whole form just for one button. Remove your form completely, which closing tag is also wrong (read Brandon's comments).

You can use this snippet in your index.html:

```
<button id="myClickButton" type="button">Click</button>
<div id="myOutput"></div>
```

Now let's trigger something when clicking on the button:

```
$("#myClickButton").click(function() {
    $.get("/output/", function(data) {
        $("#myOutput").html(data);
    }, "html");
});
```

The above code is jQuery. Please read the official documentation of jQuery. There is everything explained how to use the library.

Now let's go to your views.py.

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'yourapp/index.html')
```

Remember to put your templates in a folder `templates` within your app. It should look like this:

```
--yourproject
|
|--yourapp
|----templates
|------yourapp
|--------index.html
```

Make another view in your views.py:

```
def output(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        py_obj = mycode.test_code(10)
        return render(request, 'yourapp/output.html', {'output': py_obj.a})
```

Your output.html can be like this:

```
<p>{{ output }}</p>
```

That's all. No header, no body, nothing. This code will be inserted per AJAX on the fly in index.html.

Now let's analyze your method `code`:

```
def code(self):
    return self.a, self.b
```

Do you know what happens here? You can return only ONE value in a function. You think you're returning a and b as integers. Wrong! This method returns a tuple with two elements. This method will return `(10, 4)`.
When you call this method in your index view it just returns this tuple, but you're not assigning it to a variable, so it will go with the wind. It's useless call.

I hope this gives you an idea how you can do it. If you don't want to use JavaScript (and AJAX) you can send your form per POST and make a distinction in your view:

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'yourapp/index.html', {'output': ''})
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        py_obj = mycode.test_code(10)
        return render(request, 'yourapp/output.html', {'output': py_obj.a})
```

In this case you won't need the view output and output.html. You can use your index.html with the form inside.