# DJANGO - Call a TKINTER program using a button

Tags: python, html, django, web, tkinter

I made a program using python TKINTER, and now I need to run it in a Web application, so that everyone in the company can access it.

That's when I found out that DJANGO does this kind of service!

But I'm being beaten up here to call the TKINTER program when a button is pressed.

Can anyone give me a light? Is it doable?

I wanted something very simple, just a button on the web to run TKINTER ....

Comment: Why are you mixing web application with a static desktop application? Whatever you want to achieve in tkinter can be achieved in django itself.

Comment: tkinter can't run inside a web browser. There is the excellent [Remi](https://github.com/dddomodossola/remi) library which is similar to tkinter but runs inside a webbrowser. But as has been mentioned, if you want to use django, use that to develop the application.

Comment: No, it's not doable.

Comment: Thanks guys.  I did all my project using Tkinter, but it ended up that, for security reasons, my company said that it must be available only through a web site.

Anyway, I'm learning Django to "convert" everything to there.....I just would like to know if it would be possible to save time and have something to allow move TKinter to a web.

Comment: I checked on stackoverflow about it, try this: [How to execute file.py on HTML button press using Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54438473/how-to-execute-file-py-on-html-button-press-using-django)