# Run batch file by clicking button in django

Tags: python, html, django

I have some problem with running the file (which run program from my disc) using a button in django. So this is my batch file which i would like to run:

```
set dir=C:\Users\ciach\Desktop\openpose\bin
cd %dir%
openposedemo.exe --net_resolution 272x272 --model_folder C:\Users\ciach\Desktop\openpose\models --video C:\Users\ciach\X\Squat\P0.mp4 --write_json C:\Users\ciach\X\JSON
```

This is my run.py file which i run script by python:

```
import subprocess

def squat():
    subprocess.call(['C:/Users/ciach/Desktop/praca/django/mysite/main/file.bat'])

#squat()
```

Django files:

views.py:

```
def squat(request):
if request.method == 'POST' and 'run_script' in request.POST:
    from .run import squat
    squat()
    return redirect("/home")
```

home.html:

```
{% block content %}
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit" name="run_script">Run script</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

After clicking nothing happens. I have tried with only .bat file (without run.py) but doesn't work either. All I want is for the .bath file to start after pressing the button which will run the command as above. Is there any way to run something like that at all?
This is based on: [How to execute file.py on HTML button press using Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54438473/how-to-execute-file-py-on-html-button-press-using-django)

Python version: 3.5.0
Django version: 2.0.7

Answer (score 0):

I completly forgot about urls.py and that how its should look like:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("squat", views.squat),
]
```

I also changed home.tml

```
{% block content %}
<form action="/squat">
    <button id="stat-btn" class="btn">Run script</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Other files have not changed. Now everything is working out fine!