# Django: call a view function via a button click

Tags: python, html, django

I want to call a view function resign_game by clicking an html button. Here is what i have tried after reading some Stackoverflow posts:

```
<form action="{% url 'resign_game' %}" method="POST">
     <button type="button">RESIGN</button>
</form>
```

Here is what I have in my urls.py:

```
path('resign_game/', views.resign_current_game, name='resign_game')
```

However, the view function was never called after I clicked the button. I would appreciate your suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: and Whats in your views.py ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to execute python code by django html button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26299492/how-to-execute-python-code-by-django-html-button)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) element with `type="button"` does not send the form. Either set the type to "submit":

```
 <button type="submit">RESIGN</button>
```

Or remove the type:

```
 <button>RESIGN</button>
```